# How to use asyncpg with aiogram?

Tags: aiogram, asyncpg

I have trouble with the library asyncpg inside a code that bases on aiogram. DB code:

```
class DataBase:

    def __init__(self):
        self.db_pool = None
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(self.create_pool())

    async def create_pool(self):
        try:
            self.db_pool = await asyncpg.create_pool(Config.POSTGRES_URI)
            async with self.db_pool.acquire() as connection:
                await connection.execute('SELECT 1')
            print("\tSuccessful connection to the database")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"\tDatabase connection error: {e}")
```

The code runs, and writes that connected to the db but after first a request I get the error:

```
Cause exception while process update id=56403182 by bot id=6663434503
InterfaceError: cannot perform operation: another operation is in progress
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "beauty_experts_bot/src/services/sql.py", line 27, in add_user
    await connection.execute("""INSERT INTO user (id, username, name) VALUES (?, ?, ?)""",
  File "beauty_experts_bot/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/asyncpg/connection.py", line 319, in execute
    _, status, _ = await self._execute(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "beauty_experts_bot/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/asyncpg/connection.py", line 1659, in _execute
    result, _ = await self.__execute(
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "beauty_experts_bot/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/asyncpg/connection.py", line 1684, in __execute
    return await self._do_execute(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "beauty_experts_bot/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/asyncpg/connection.py", line 1711, in _do_execute
    stmt = await self._get_statement(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "beauty_experts_bot/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/asyncpg/connection.py", line 397, in _get_statement
    statement = await self._protocol.prepare(
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "asyncpg/protocol/protocol.pyx", line 168, in prepare
RuntimeError: Task <Task pending name='Task-29' coro=<Dispatcher._process_update() running at /home/davyd/MY_DATA/programming/tmp_project/beauty_experts_bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py:308>> got Future <Future pending cb=[Protocol._on_waiter_completed()]> attached to a different loop

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "beauty_experts_bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 308, in _process_update
    response = await self.feed_update(bot, update, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "beauty_experts_bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 157, in feed_update
    response = await self.update.wrap_outer_middleware(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "beauty_experts_bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/middlewares/error.py", line 25, in __call__
    return await handler(event, data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "beauty_experts_bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/middlewares/user_context.py", line 27, in __call__
    return await handler(event, data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "beauty_experts_bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiogram/fsm/middleware.py", line 39, in __call__
    return await handler(event, data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "beauty_experts_bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/event/telegram.py", line 120, in trigger
    return await wrapped_inner(event, kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "beauty_experts_bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/event/handler.py", line 42, in call
    return await wrapped()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "beauty_experts_bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 275, in _listen_update
    return await self.propagate_event(update_type=update_type, event=event, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "beauty_experts_bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/router.py", line 116, in propagate_event
    return await observer.wrap_outer_middleware(_wrapped, event=event, data=kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "beauty_experts_bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/router.py", line 111, in _wrapped
    return await self._propagate_event(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "beauty_experts_bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/router.py", line 136, in _propagate_event
    response = await observer.trigger(event, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "beauty_experts_bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/event/telegram.py", line 120, in trigger
    return await wrapped_inner(event, kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "beauty_experts_bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/event/handler.py", line 42, in call
    return await wrapped()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "beauty_experts_bot/src/handlers/basic.py", line 15, in start
    await db.add_user(
  File "beauty_experts_bot/src/services/sql.py", line 26, in add_user
    async with self.db_pool.acquire() as connection:
  File "beauty_experts_bot/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/asyncpg/pool.py", line 220, in release
    raise ex
  File "beauty_experts_bot/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/asyncpg/pool.py", line 210, in release
    await self._con.reset(timeout=budget)
  File "beauty_experts_bot/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/asyncpg/connection.py", line 1366, in reset
    await self.execute(reset_query, timeout=timeout)
  File "beauty_experts_bot/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/asyncpg/connection.py", line 317, in execute
    return await self._protocol.query(query, timeout)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "asyncpg/protocol/protocol.pyx", line 323, in query
  File "asyncpg/protocol/protocol.pyx", line 707, in asyncpg.protocol.protocol.BaseProtocol._check_state
asyncpg.exceptions._base.InterfaceError: cannot perform operation: another operation is in progress
```

My request to db:

```
db = DataBase()

async def start(message: Message) -> None:
    await db.add_user(
        user_id=message.from_user.id,
        username=message.from_user.username,
        name=message.from_user.full_name
    )
```

I suspect the error is not working properly with asynchron but can't figure out what, I also attach the code to run the bot:

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher
import asyncio
from aiogram.enums.parse_mode import ParseMode

from config import Config
from handlers import basic, specialist, admin
from utils.commands import set_commands


async def start():
    bot = Bot(token=Config.TOKEN, parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)
    dp = Dispatcher(bot=bot)

    # REGISTER HANDLERS
    basic.register_handlers(dp=dp)
    specialist.register_handlers(dp=dp)
    admin.register_handlers(dp=dp)

    await set_commands(bot=bot)

    try:
        await dp.start_polling(bot)
    finally:
        await bot.send_message(chat_id=Config.ADMIN_ID, text="<b>BOT STOPPED</b>")
        await bot.session.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(start())
```

I did everything according to the documentation

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by starting to call create_pool not from **init** that is contained in Database, but directly from the initial function async def start in which the bot itself is started. The reason for the error is that asynchronous loops conflicted with each other